# Imitate paragraph spacing in visual line mode

Tags: newlines, visual-line-mode, line-spacing

I write long texts using `org-mode` and `visual-line-mode`. Each long line, wrapping over several visual lines, looks like a "paragraph", and behaves similarly to a paragraph in a traditional word processor.

I would like to see some extra spacing between such "paragraphs", that is, between lines, but *not* between visual lines within the wrapped long line. (`(setq line-spacing 0.5)` is obviously not it.)

Is this achievable in a GUI version of Emacs? I use the build from https://emacsformacosx.com/, but would consider switching to a different build.

Answer (score 4):

This same or similar question was previously asked on stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838516/how-to-set-paragraph-spacing-in-emacs  Here is a regurgitation of my prior answer:

The following code alters the visual display by adding an additional new visual line, but does *not* actually add new lines to the current document:

```lisp
(aset (or buffer-display-table
  (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))) ?\n [?\n?\n])
```

To restore it back the way it was:

```lisp
(aset (or buffer-display-table
  (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))) ?\n [?\n])
```

Here is a convenient method using keyboard shortcuts to implement this idea:

```lisp
(defun one-carriage-return-looks-like-two ()
(interactive)
  (aset (or buffer-display-table
    (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))) ?\n [?\n?\n]))

(defun one-carriage-return-looks-like-one ()
(interactive)
  (aset (or buffer-display-table
    (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))) ?\n [?\n]))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c 1") 'one-carriage-return-looks-like-one)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c 2") 'one-carriage-return-looks-like-two)
```