# org-mode additional line-spacing after paragraphs, list items and headings

Tags: org-mode, line-spacing

It has been [asked before,](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39155/imitate-paragraph-spacing-in-visual-line-mode) but the answers are a bit old, and did not work for me. So I am hoping that the situation has changed a bit.

I would like to modify the vertical space around headings, at the end of lists and paragraphs to visually group them. A bit like a context specific `line-spacing` at the newline character. Is there a way of doing this? [Here](https://zzamboni.org/post/beautifying-org-mode-in-emacs/) I have found that it is possible to change the font for each org-level. Would that be a good entry point?

Comment: Is the question about how the text appears in the emacs buffer or is it about how it appears when exported (e.g. to LaTeX or HTML)?

Comment: How it appears in emacs.